# How do I get my npm module's JSdoc documentation for functions to show up in users' VScode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm kinda new to VScode, and TypeScript. I'm trying to publish a tiny module with in-depth documentation to npm, and have users' VScode installations show beautiful type-directed instructions when consuming my efforts.

When I try typing `console.assert` in VScode, I get something like this:

[image: a screenshot of VScode with a hover-popup showing human-written documentation for console.assert inline]

Cool! That's what I want my users to see!

However, when I try importing my own module, I seem to get *types* … but hovering over a callsite, I only see:

[image: a screenshot of the hover-popup for another function, showing type information, but no human-written description]

A distinct lack of … any of [the carefully-detailed writeup I've published in the source-code](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/ocaml-string-convert/blob/master/index.ts#L119-L145).

What is necessary of a JavaScript documentation-comment to convince VScode (and, hopefully, other editors) to display it inline? Perhaps-relatedly, why does VScode say "alias" instead of "function" or "method" for my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the documentation of your method when hovering over it you have to wrap it in a [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html) formated documentation comment.
For example:

`my_lib.ts`:

```ts
/**
 * converts something to something
 * @param eldritch_horror This my argument
 * @returns the converted stuff.
 */
export function fromFakeUTF8String(eldritch_horror: string): string {
    return 'hello world';
}
```

Now when your users import it and hover over the method call they will get the following result:

[image: Example]